# Kubernetes: How can I save logs of the pod before termination using PreStop hook?

Tags: debugging, logging, kubernetes, hook

I want the pods running in my cluster to save their logs just before termination somewhere, so that I can access these logs later and know the termination reason. 
Can this be accomplished using the PreStop hook? If yes, please guide me how to do so. 
Any other approaches are also welcomed.

Comment: [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in the Kubernetes documentation has a high-level description of what's possible and some sample setups.  Generally these involve running some other process to manage logs continuously and not necessarily in a hook (which isn't guaranteed to fire).

Answer (score 1):

Use fluentd or fluent bit to send logs to a log aggregator system such as elastic search(EFK stack) or splunk.

Fluentd can run as daemonset in each node and send logs to EFK/Splunk.

Fluentbit can  run as a sidecar and send logs to EFK/Splunk

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#basic-logging-in-kubernetes